# Асинхронные запросы PHP

Tags: php, асинхронность

Подскажите как лучше организовать асинхронные запросы в PHP?

Мне нужно отправить запрос, получить ответ и произвести некоторые вычисления с этими данными.

Буду премного благодарен за любую информацию.

Пробовал с popen, примерно так, но что-то подсказывает, что я делаю не так:

```
$url = "someurl";
for ($i=1;$i<=2000;$i++) {
    if(($fp = popen('curl "'.$url.'"', "r")) ) {
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $data[] = fread($fp, 1024);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

    someFunctionForWorkWithData($data);
}
```

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте запускал скрипт как процесс и так бы работал. Иногда делают запуск скрипта и при появлении определенных данных запускают потоки работать с ними, а центральный скрипт продолжает работать.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать мультикурл, он дает некоторую асинхронность

```
$mc = curl_multi_init();
$c = [];
for ($i=1;$i<=2000;$i++) {
  $c[$i] = curl_init();
  //набиваете $c[$i] нужными вам данными
  curl_multi_add_handle($mc,$c[$i]);
}

$active = null;
do {
  $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mc, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
  if (curl_multi_select($mc) != -1) {
    do {
      $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mc, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
  }
}

$responses = [];
for ($i=1;$i<=2000;$i++) {
  $responses[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($c[$i]);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mc,$c[$i]);
}

curl_multi_close($mc);
```

Comment: Некоторую синхронность - это вроде как немножко беременна?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что с помощью данного подхода можно асинхронно отправлять несколько запросов, но обрабатывать их все равно придется синхронно - по приходу ответа на все запросы.
В любом случае, определенный выигрыш по времени так можно получить